# unable to select dropdown which has 1 index value

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select one option from multiple options in the dropdown but as it shows index value is 1 so unable to select

Answer (score 0):

You get not really details, but in the case you have :

```
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

to select the second option, you do :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("myselect")).click();
//you can add a check of visibility of options (WebDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfLocatedElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='myselect']/option"))
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='myselect']/option[@value='2']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("myselect")).click(); //to close the dropdown
```